# Data for Madelung Constants

Tags: energy, crystal-structure, ionic-compounds, databases, lattices

Where can I find data for the Madelung constants for various ionic compounds? Specifically, I am looking at silicon tetrachloride, yttrium (III) chloride, zirconium (IV) oxynitrate hydrate, niobium (V) chloride, molybdenum (V) chloride, hafnium tetrachloride, tantalum (V) chloride, and tungsten hexachloride.

Is there a database that has already-determined Madelung constants? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want Madelung constants for this set? Apart from the first two (and even then it's debatable for Zr4+) the ionic model is going to be an extremely poor representation of such systems.

Comment: I wanted the Madelung constants because I wanted to calculate the lattice energy using the Born-Lande equation. Am fairly new to this kind of chemistry, sorry if I am misinterpreting some terms. Would there be an alternate method to determine the lattice energy?

Comment: The Madelung constant is the signed sum of the reciprocal lattice distances so you must have the x-ray structure and then from the unit cell and using symmetry calculate numerically all the distances, possible many hundreds until the summation converges.